# Multiple search criteria django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

Im following the Django docs in order to build a multiple search criteria form. My first question is if this should be the correct method of filtering values in the query and also how can i add the foreignkeys and m2m displayed as selects and multipleselects in the search criteria.. This is my code so far. Thanks

Forms

```
class SearchPropertyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Nombre'}))
    activity = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Activity.objects.all(), widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Actividad'}))
    currency = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Currency.objects.all(), widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Moneda'}))
    price_from = forms.IntegerField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Precio-Desde'}))
    price_to = forms.IntegerField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Precio-Hasta'}))
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Category.objects.all(), widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs = {'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Categorias'}))
```

Model

```
class Property(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "properties"

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    sqft = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2)
    beds = models.IntegerField()
    baths = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places = 2)
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null = True, blank = True)
    currency_type = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
    activity_type = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    edition_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

View

```
def search_properties(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchPropertyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            activity = form.cleaned_data['activity']
            currency = form.cleaned_data['currency']
            price_from = form.cleaned_data['price_from']
            price_to = form.cleaned_data['price_to']
            categories = form.cleaned_data['categories']

            properties = Property.objects.filter(name__icontains = name).filter(
            activity_type__exact = int(activity)).filter(
            currency_type__exact = int(currency)).filter(
            price_from__gte = int(price_from)).filter(
            price_from__lte = int(price_to)).filter(
            categories__exact = int(categories))

            return render(request, 'properties/search_properties.html', {
                'properties': properties,
                'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
                'form':form,
            })

    else:
        form = SearchPropertyForm()

    properties = Property.objects.filter(status = True)

    return render(request, 'properties/search_properties.html', {
        'properties': properties,
        'media_url': settings.MEDIA_URL,
        'form':form,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Q` object in case you are trying to do a `or` query.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

so your code could be like this.

```
from django.db.models import Q
properties = Property.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains = name)|
                Q(activity_type__exact = int(activity))|
                Q(currency_type__exact = int(currency))|
                Q(price_from__gte = int(price_from))|
                Q(price_from__lte = int(price_to))|
                Q(categories__exact = int(categories))
```

In the `Q` object `|` (pipe) represents an `or` query and `&` represents an `and` query.

So this will return if any of the query is matched.

For the forms section I use Modelform like the following which automatically takes the foreign keys and the multiselects.

```
class SearchPropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = ('name', 'activity','currency', 'price_form')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Q` objects, or simply use [`django-filter`](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html):

> Django-filter provides a simple way to filter down a queryset based on parameters a user provides.

Once you have it installed, create a `forms.py` (since a filter is a type of form), and inside it add the following:

```
import django_filters

from .models import Property

class PropertyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
```

Then, you have to wire it up from your `views.py`:

```
from .forms import PropertyFilter

def search(request):
   f = PropertyFilter(request.GET, Property.objects.all())
   return render(request, 'search.html', {'filter': f})
```

Your template `search.html`:

```
<form method="GET" role="form">
   {{ f.form }}
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% if f|length %}
   {% for obj in f %}
       {{ obj }}
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   Sorry, no results for your search criteria
{% endif %}
```